# Can slowms be set on each individual database in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using `db.setProfilingLevel(1, 1000)` to set the profile level for each database. I see the level can be set for each database but the `slowms` is a global state. Is there any way to set this value for each individual database?

If I can't set it for each individual database, why there is a method `db.setProfilingLevel(level, slowms)` accept the second parameter as `slowms`. It looks like this parameter is for global value rather than database value. What is confused is this method is specific for setting a single database profile level but for some reasons it also set slowms in global setting.

Comment: Sadly, answer is no... Without changing source code.

Comment: @JJussi Thanks for reply. I have updated my question could you let me know what you think about the method `setProfilingLevel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MongoDB documentation of `MongoDB High Availability` by `@Afshin Mehrabani` & MongoDB BOL [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel)

To enable profiling for a MongoDB , you can use following function:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(level, slowms)
```

where

**`level`** - This refers to verbosity level of profiling

**`slowms`** - This is optional. It is used to define the slow operation threshold in milliseconds.

The following command is a sample of issuing the proceding function in the mongo interactive shell:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1,1000)
```

so, the proceding command enables profiling for the MongoDB instance with level 1 and threshold 1000 milliseconds.

The output of this command in the mongo shell is as the following below

```
>db.setProfilingLevel(1,1000)
{"was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1}
```

The MongoDB engine supports three main levels of proviling. The following table shows the three different level of profilling:

```
Level     Description

0        This indicates that profilling is disabled

1        This refer to only slow log operations

2        This refers to all log operations
```

When using the first level of profiling , the database's profiler doesn't save anything related to operations. With level `1`, the profiler logs slow operations.

There is a setting parameter that defines the slow operations threshold. Using the `slowOpThresholdMs` configuration parameter, you can define a threshold for slow operations. Then, the profiler logs operations with slower execution time than the define value.

To define the `slowOpThresholdMs` parameter, you can either use a configuration file to define the value or you can pass the value to the second parameter of the `setProfilingLevel` function.

By using level `2` of profiling , the profiler records all operations without considering any conditions.

To understand the structure of this function better, consider the following command :

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 1000)
```

after issuing the preceding command , the database profiler records all operations with an execution time greater than 1000 milliseconds.

Note : Using the profiler negatively performance because the profiler records redundant for a part, or the entire database operations. It's recommended to keep it off unless you need to diagnose the database.

After configuring the profiler engine , you can query logs from database using the `system.profile` collection.

As per MongoDB Jira Blog [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4785) The slowms constant is not per database but is process wide.

```
> db.setProfilingLevel(1,1000)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1 }
> db.getProfilingStatus()
{ "was" : 1, "slowms" : 1000 }
> use test2
switched to db test2
> db.setProfilingLevel(1,2)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 1000, "ok" : 1 }
> db.getProfilingStatus()
{ "was" : 1, "slowms" : 2 }
> use test
switched to db test
> db.getProfilingStatus()
{ "was" : 1, "slowms" : 2 }
```

Notice how slowms went to 2 in the test database... That is not good.

As [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5266) was closed won't fix but if the syntax of db.setProfilingLevel is changed to only affect a single database there will be requirement to have syntax to set globally what slowms is (without having to restart mongod with new slowms setting).

Note that this change as proposed is backwards breaking to every instruction given by our support which is currently assumed to have global effect.

Recommend we consider non-backwards breaking syntax, like **`db.setProfilingLevel(0,1,false)`** where last parameter is "applyGlobally" and by default is true. (or applyToCurrentDB only and by default is false).

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Why does the method `db.setProfilingLevel(1, 1000)` change `slowms` setting for all databases in the instance?

Comment: @ZhaoYi , As per MongoDB jira blog https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4785 db.setProfilingLevel(0,1,false) where last parameter is "applyGlobally" and by default is true.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Jira.mongodb.org is an issue tracker (for feature suggestions and improvements), not a blog. Unless an issue is resolved with a released server `fixVersion`, syntax discussion such as your quote from SERVER-4785 is a proposal rather than a working example. As at MongoDB 3.6, the `slowms` threshold can only be set as a global configuration value for a `mongod` instance.

Answer (score 2):

setProfilingLevel actually affects two things. First parameter (level) tells when system writes to profile -collection (0-never, 1-only when slower than slowms or 2-always). Second parameter (slowms) affects actually always to syslog output of ALL databases. So, with db.setProfilingLevel(0,-1), nothing is ever written to profile-collection, but ALL queries (of all DBs) are written to mongod.log